# Capturing all subgroups

Tags: java, regex, scala

How I can capture all repeating groups?

I wanted to have one single match for all letters separated by dash. I was expecting to see 3 groups and in each of them a letter. What is happening? Can I get all the groups?

```
val matcher = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(?:(\\w)-?)+").matcher("a-b-c")
matcher.matches()
println(matcher.groupCount())
println(matcher.group(0))
println(matcher.group(1))
```

This prints

```
1
a-b-c
c
```

I was expecting to get something like

```
3
a-b-c
a
```

Comment: it won't be possible to get 3 group counts other than using this `(\\w+)-?(\\w+)-?(\\w+)` regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\\w)(?=-|$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/14

Your regex captures a `character` which has `-` ahead of it.So the last character has no `-` ahead of it.Also in groups regex engine remembers the last group.So you were getting `c`.